# How to get and save nearby dates in state dynamically?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building navigation with buttons I need to get five state values selected data, initially current date. and two earlier dates and two later dates. How can I use date value in React state to get 0-5 dates: values for buttons?

```js
import React, { Component} from "react";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import ButtonToolbar from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

class DateNav extends Component{
  state = {
      date: new Date(),
      dates: [
        {
          id: 0,
          date: new Date(), // -2
          text: new Date().toLocaleString()
        },        
        {
          id: 1,
          date: new Date(), // -1
          text: new Date().toLocaleString()
        },        
        {
          id: 2,
          date: new Date(),
          text: new Date().toLocaleString()
        },        
        {
          id: 3,
          date: new Date(),
          text: new Date().toLocaleString()
        },        
        {
          id: 4,
          date: new Date(), // +1
          text: new Date().toLocaleString()
        },        
        {
          id: 5,
          date: new Date(), // +2
          text: new Date().toLocaleString()
        },        
      ]
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="DateNav">
          <button>{this.state.dates[0].text}</button>
          <button>{this.state.dates[1].text}</button>
          <button>{this.state.dates[2].text}</button>
          <button>{this.state.dates[3].text}</button>
          <button>{this.state.dates[4].text}</button>       
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default DateNav;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get todays date, and add a relative offset to it.

```js
const getDate = (relative = 0) => {
  let date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + relative);
  return date;
};

const state = {
  dates: [
    {
      id: 0,
      date: getDate(-2), // -2
      text: getDate(-2).toLocaleString()
    },        
    {
      id: 1,
      date: getDate(-1), // -1
      text: getDate(-1).toLocaleString()
    },        
    {
      id: 2,
      date: getDate(),
      text: getDate().toLocaleString()
    },        
    {
      id: 3,
      date: getDate(1), // +1
      text: getDate(1).toLocaleString()
    },        
    {
      id: 4,
      date: getDate(2), // +2
      text: getDate(2).toLocaleString()
    },   
  ],
};

console.log(state);
```

If you want them relative from a specified date:

```js
const getDate = (date, relative = 0) => {
  let newDate = date ? new Date(date) : new Date();
  newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + relative);
  return newDate;
};

const date = "October 15, 1985";
const state = {
  dates: [
    {
      id: 0,
      date: getDate(date, -2), // -2
      text: getDate(date, -2).toLocaleString()
    },        
    {
      id: 1,
      date: getDate(date, -1), // -1
      text: getDate(date, -1).toLocaleString()
    },        
    {
      id: 2,
      date: getDate(date),
      text: getDate(date).toLocaleString()
    },        
    {
      id: 3,
      date: getDate(date, 1), // +1
      text: getDate(date, 1).toLocaleString()
    },        
    {
      id: 4,
      date: getDate(date, 2), // +2
      text: getDate(date, 2).toLocaleString()
    },   
  ],
};

console.log(state);
```

And for the sake of DRY-ness

```js
const getDate = date => (relative = 0) => {
  let newDate = date ? new Date(date) : new Date();
  newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + relative);
  return newDate;
};

const getDates = (date, offsets = [0]) => {
  const getDateOffset = getDate(date);
  return offsets.map((offset, index) => {
    const offsetDate = getDateOffset(offset);
    return {
      id: index,
      date: offsetDate,
      text: offsetDate.toLocaleString(),
    };
  });
};

const date = "October 15, 1985";
const state = {
  dates: getDates(date, [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]),
};

console.log(state);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `setState()` method, calling setState will update your state and re-render the component by calling `render()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the dates array and format dates object as you like.

I have taken the day as an example.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.today = new Date().getDate()
    this.state = {
      dates: [
        {
          id: 0,
          text: (this.today - 2)
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          text: (this.today - 1)
        },        
        {
          id: 2,
          text: this.today
        },        
        {
          id: 3,
          text: (this.today + 1)
        },        
        {
          id: 4,
          text: (this.today + 2)
        }    
      ]
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.dates.map((date) => {
          return (<button key={date.id}>{date.text.toLocaleString()}</button>)
        })} 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to init individual date.

Instead of that, you can use `Array(5).fill().map` function.

In map function, you need to use only index parameter but not value(actually it is undefined).

Here it goes.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.updateDateNav(); // init Dates state according to today(no parameters).
}

updateDateNav = (currentDate = new Date()) => {
  const Dates = Array(5).fill().map((unusedValue, index) => {
    const calculatedDate = new Date();
    calculatedDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - ( index - 2));
    return {
      id: index,
      date: calculatedDate,
      text: calculatedDate.toLocaleString(),
    }
  });
  this.setState({ Dates });
};

onClickSth = () => {
 // update Navigation dates according to current selected Date
 this.updateDateNav(this.state.Dates[2].date);
}
```